# SQL (Impala): UNION ALL in multiple tables with the same prefix

Tags: sql, bigdata, impala

Let's say we have 4 tables with the same exact columns inside:
table_001 
table_002 
table_003 
table_004 
To combine all the tables into one table, we can use `UNION ALL` as follows:

```
select * from table_001
union all
select * from table_002
union all
select * from table_003
union all
select * from table_004;
```

It seems easy for 4 tables, but I think it will be tedious if there are more tables.
Is there any way to combine all the tables with the same prefix by using a wildcard (for example, combine all table with the pattern 'table_00%')

Comment: Fix your data model!  You should not have multiple tables containing the same entities.  All this data should be in the same table.

Comment: Short answer; no.  You would need to write you own code that reads the database to generate a list of table that match your requirements, then have some code which takes that list and generate the sql in the pattern you've described.  Sounds tedious?  That because you're using an anti-pattern.  What you should be doing is using impala's native ability to partition a table (it's effectively what you're trying to do manually).  https://docs.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/latest/topics/impala_partitioning.html